# Bald Saiyan goes Super Saiyan?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In Dragon Ball Z when someone goes Super Saiyan their hair turns the telltale gold colour. How would you know if a bald saiyan (such as Nappa) were to achieve this level? Besides the obvious increase in strength, speed etc. how would you be able to tell they'd gone super saiyan just by looking at them?

Comment: Check here: https://www.google.it/search?q=nappa+super+sayan&safe=off&biw=2049&bih=1001&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QsARqFQoTCObuw5D06sgCFUTpFAod_IgJUw&dpr=0.67

Comment: In Budokai Tenkaichi 3, in the versus mode screen, Nappa thinks about what he would look like as a Super Saiyan and says "Think if I went Super Saiyan, my goatee would grow?" lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their eyes and eyebrows change colour too, so perhaps that? Also, possibly the hair on the tail would change colour too (Though all the saiyans that could transform had lost their tails, except Broly)

Comment: Yeah, but even the Saiyans with hair usually get some growth in theirs. So maybe he could get a cool blonde buzz-cut. Haha..

Answer (score 1):

Green eyes. Even if a Saiyan had no hair at all, their eye color would be a dead giveaway.

[image]